# Show the data from two date fields ordered by the name of the month

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have two date fields. need to pull the data based on this two date fields and display it  on monthly order (in words) like JAN , FEB... in MySQL.

As of now my query is:

```
SELECT `firstname` , `gender` , MONTH( `dol` ) AS 'month' FROM `student_details`
WHERE `doa` = '2015-03-01' AND `dol` = '2015-06-17'
```

but this query is not working.

I need it to display the records based on the months in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
SELECT `firstname` , `gender` , MONTHNAME( `dol` ) AS 'month' FROM `student_details`
WHERE `doa` = '2015-03-01' AND `dol` = '2015-06-17'
```

Below SQL give exact result i think.

```
SELECT `firstname` , `gender` , SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME( `dol` ),1,3) AS 'month' FROM `student_details`
WHERE `doa` = '2015-03-01' AND `dol` = '2015-06-17'
```

Between date these sql will useful to you.

```
 SELECT `firstname` , `gender` , SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME( `dol` ),1,3) AS 'month' FROM `student_details`
WHERE `doa` BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND DATE_ADD('2015-06-30' , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Thank you.

Comment: i need all the data based on range from 2015 -03-01 to 2015-06-17,now i m get only the data `dol` = '2015-06-17' and need to order by month?

Comment: i need it as all data from data between the field doa = 2015-01-01 to dol = 2015-06-30 and not as you mentioned above

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted :) Thank you  Venkatesh Panabaka. Could you tell me why we are adding INTERVAL 1 DAY!!

Comment: we are using between statement it display one day less because of that i added one day extra. Can you give a tick mark and up vote please...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80758/discussion-between-acube-and-venkatesh-panabaka).

Answer (score 1):

Please check below :

```
SELECT `firstname` , `gender` ,  DATE_FORMAT(`dol`,'%b') AS 'month' FROM `student_details`
WHERE `doa` = '2015-03-01' AND `dol` = '2015-06-17'
```

Comment: Thanks but this query returns the value only for dol = 2015-06-17, i need data from doa date to dol date